# Oracle INNER JOIN does not work but CARTESIAN join works

Tags: c#, oracle, inner-join

I'm getting a very weird error.
If I write my query using INNER JOIN, like below:

```
 String query = @"SELECT     *
                  FROM       BKING CCVB
                  INNER JOIN SEM S ON CCVB.BKING_REQ_DTM BETWEEN S.ST_D AND S.END_D";
 OracleCommand dbCommand = new OracleCommand(query, Connection);
 OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(dbCommand);
 OracleCommandBuilder builder = new OracleCommandBuilder(adapter);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 adapter.Fill(dt);
 return dt;
```

The query fails with the following error message:

> {Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

But when I change to cartesian join, it is fine:

```
 String query = @"SELECT     *
                  FROM       BKING CCVB, SEM S 
                  WHERE      CCVB.BKING_REQ_DTM BETWEEN S.ST_D AND S.END_D";
 OracleCommand dbCommand = new OracleCommand(query, Connection);
 OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(dbCommand);
 OracleCommandBuilder builder = new OracleCommandBuilder(adapter);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 adapter.Fill(dt);
 return dt;
```

Any particular reason why it fails? And how to solve?

Comment: Are you certain that this problem is reproducible?  I mean, the error message you are seeing is pretty bland, and doesn't even mention an actual table/view name.

Comment: that's the error message I'm getting, no table name. Oracle error message is like that, it's a lot of pain to debug.

Comment: When you run that inner join query directly against Oracle, what happens?

Comment: It can show the result table. The strange thing is that when I try to do `SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_PRIVS` in the program, I can get both of the table name. So it does exist, but somehow if I use the `INNER JOIN` syntax, it does not work.

Comment: Are you using a really old Oracle adapter in your C# code?  That would be the next thing I would check.

Comment: I'm using ODP. NET. `Assembly Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, `, which is part of `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.19.3.0\lib\net40\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the user you're connecting sqlplus with and the user your code is using, are the same?

Comment: Yes. Because when I use cartesian join, I am able to get the result, but using inner join, it will throw an error. If the user is wrong, then either both fails or both are successful.